# What is a good cheap midi controller?

Tags: midi

I'm looking for a cheap midi controller keyboard. I would primarily use this for playing around with music production through Reason 8. I will also occasionally use it to play synth sounds live through my laptop with Reason.

## Requirements

- Must have a USB output, no sound outputs are necessary.
- Must have at least 49 keys. More would be nice but not necessary.
- Must have a mod wheel and a pitch bend wheel separately. (my current controller has the two combined together, which is obnoxious to say the least)
- Must have reprogrammable faders and knobs.

## Preferences

- USB-powered would be nice, but isn't a must.
- Light, and easy to carry around.
- Button pads would be nice.
- Durable

I have no brand preferences. I would like to spend less money if possible. Ideal price would be under $100, but I could see myself going up to $150 if it was a significant improvement in quality.